# How does getting a SSL certificate relates to my Node.js application?

Tags: security, node.js, ssl, linode

I have a Node.js application running on my Linode server and my server will need SSL.

I understand I need to purchase one, something like this: http://www.namecheap.com/ssl-certificates/comodo/essential-ssl-certificate.aspx

I understand I need to get a dedicated IP address and follow these instructions: http://library.linode.com/security/ssl-certificates/commercial

What I don't understand is how my Node application would know about this SSL certificate? Does my Node application care?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run a https server.

If you are running expressjs you can do something like this - using the certificate and key you get form your ssl provider.

```
var express = require('express')
  , fs = require("fs");

var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('security/privatekey.pem').toString();
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('security/certificate.pem').toString();  

// to enable https
var app = module.exports = express.createServer({key: privateKey, cert: certificate});
```

Hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

You can check out this [link](http://silas.sewell.org/blog/2010/06/03/node-js-https-ssl-server-example/) - this guy is using a standard node server implementation and not express. However i'm not sure if the security api has changed - this post is nearly 2 years old.

Answer (score 1):

Your server needs to be configured with a certificate (and its private key) because it proves its identity to the users. The server certificate is presented to the browser during the TLS handshake, when the HTTPS connection starts.

This should only affect the configuration of the server itself. Actual application code served by the server needs not know about it (and probably shouldn't, so as to reduce the risks of leaking the private key via incorrect code).

Comment: I 99% agree with this, however if you allow the app to run on either http or https, it at least needs to be aware which protocol the request came in via, so that the correct base protocol can be used when generating links in templates and responses, etc.

Comment: You could use protocol relative URLs to avoid needing to do that dynamically. A url that's along the lines of "//stackoverflow.com" will automatically use the same protocol as the current page. There will still be cases where you'd wanna ensure the visitor only accesses certain 'pages' via https, though (such as login pages).

Comment: @Kitsune, this isn't related at all to protocol-relative URLs. Using such URLs don't make the server listen to port 443 or configure it to serve pages over HTTPS. It's just not going to happen by magic.

Comment: @Bruno, I was referring to Ryan LaBarre's comment (should have added the @-name, but it slipped my mind), specifically about 'generating links in templates', not your original post. Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: @Kitsune, ah sorry, I read your comment too quickly. It makes sense of course.